# Returning a null pointer from a C function, comparison seg faults

Tags: c, pointers, null, segmentation-fault, return

I'm working on a file system simulator using C. 
My Node struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
  char name[64];
  char type;
  struct node* child;
  struct node* sibling;
  struct node* parent;
}Node;
```

My recursive function, findNode(), returns NULL if it can't find a node in the tree with a specific name.

```
Node* findNode(char* name, Node* start)
{
  printf("inside findNode, looking for %s, starting at %s\n", name, start->name);
  Node* current = start;
  if(strcmp(name, current->name) == 0)
  {
    printf("inside findNoe, node found.\n");
    return current;
  }
  if(current->sibling->name != 0)
  {
    return findNode(name, current->sibling);
  }
  if(current->child->name != 0)
  {
    return findNode(name, current->child);
  }
  printf("inside findNode, node not found.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Upon calling findNode() and comparing it to 0, my program seg faults.

```
if(findNode(bname,current) != 0) //seg fault here
  {
    printf("Error: node with basename already exists under directory name.\n"); 
    return;
  }
```

I know that the program is reaching the end of findNode() when it hasn't found a node, because it prints the "node not found" message.

I'm under the impression that it's possible to return 0 when the return type is a pointer. I've tried using NULL, and saving the result to a Node* variable before comparing it. Neither worked.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
Code now looks like the following. There's a new check at the beginning to see if `current` is NULL, and I've stopped trying to access `child` and `sibling` names.

```
Node* findNode(char* name, Node* start)
{
  Node* current = start;
  if(current == NULL)
  {
    printf("inside findNode, NULL passed in\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  printf("inside findNode, looking for %s, starting at %s\n", name, current->name);
  if(strcmp(name, current->name) == 0)
  {
    printf("inside findNode, node found.\n");
    return current;
  }
  if(current->sibling != NULL && current->sibling != root)
  {
    return findNode(name, current->sibling);
  }
  if(current->child != NULL && current->sibling != root)
  {
    return findNode(name, current->child);
  }
  printf("inside findNode, node not found.\n");
  return NULL;
}
```

First test: "/" and my root node, name "/".
Second test: "hello" and my root node, name "/". "hello" should not be found.

```
inside findNode, looking for /, starting at /
inside findNode, node found.
inside findNode, looking for hello, starting at /
inside findNode, node not found.
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Segfault occurs when you are trying to access a NULL pointer. For an example if `a` is a null pointer and you were trying to access `a->name`(that is an attribute of a), then segfault occurs. Is your problem similar to this? I can provide detailed description if this is like it.

Comment: `return 0;`, why not `return NULL;`? technically, a null pointer is typically defined as `(void *) 0;` anyway, and it makes your code easier to read

Comment: S_kar, I don't think that's it. The only time I try to access an attribute of a struct is within `findNode()`, and `start` and `current` aren't NULL because `findNode()` makes it to the end. I don't want to compare attributes, I want to compare pointers in order to determine if `findNode()` found anything or not.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the comparison itself is seg faulting. You are misinterpreting the data somehow. Why don't you just run your program in a debugger? It will tell you precisely which line of code causes the segfault. Likely within one of the recursive calls of `findNode`. For example, you don't check whether `current`  is NULL before dereferencing it.

Comment: Elias, I've tried both. `0` is just what my professor uses so I thought I'd stay consistent. Do they not mean the same thing?

Comment: @MeganMcPherson you are accessing the attributes of the pointer inside findNode. So, in your code if `start` is NULL, then it will cause segfault.

Comment: `printf("inside findNode, looking for %s, starting at %s\n", name, start->name);`. This is the most likely cause of the seg fault. Occurs when `start` is NULL. And would likely result in no `printf` output so you don't see that. Again, the best advice you can get is to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: But there's already a `"inside findNode, node not found.\n"` been printed and current->sibling/child->name is accessed before the call.

Comment: @Rob11311 Think recursively. In any case, dereferencing a NULL pointer is Undefined Behaviour. Which means there doesn't have to be a seg fault immediately. It may occur on the first access but it may be the second, or the third or not at all. That is the nature of UB.

Comment: I have done, S_kar's answer didn't fit what was described, I see what you mean but the cause of segfault is likely to be the child pointer not being setup correctly

Comment: I would love to use a debugger, but I'm in Linux using gedit and I don't know of any good IDEs for C. Should have mentioned that. 
I changed `findNode()` to include a check for `start == NULL` at the very beginning and my `NULL passed in` message never printed.

Comment: Lots of ppl do fine without debuggers, you need to check that sibling & child are valid nodes

Comment: Also changed `findNode()` to not try accessing `current->sibling->name` and `current->child->name` and instead just `current->sibling` and `current->child`. It still seg faults in the same place.

Comment: The Linux debugger is gdb, think gedit is the GNOME text editor.. CODEBLOCKS is an IDE that works under Linux for C.  But you really will be able to find it, without an IDE or debugger, if you check your assumptions.  If sibling & child look right, how are you allocating the memory for them? Are they automatic on the stack, in which case you have likely over-written them, making later function calls.  The Nodes need to be allocated with malloc or similar

Comment: As @Rob11311 pointed out, there is insufficient information. Maybe if you could give the test cases that you tried, then the problem could be determined. But what i think is the best way is that checking if the pointer is null before accessing that.

Comment: @MeganMcPherson You don't need an IDE to run a debugger. Though you certainly could set that up if you wanted to. Just run `gdb my_program`. `gdb` is the standard debugger in Linux. After running that `gdb` command, within `gdb` run `go` to start the program. That should seg fault. Then run `backtrace` to get the full stack trace, including line of code, that causes the seg fault. Read the [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) for more details on how to use gdb.

Comment: Megan don't need a debugger to find the error .. most likely in this case & very often in general, where the program crashes IS NOT where the error is!!

Comment: you guys have been helpful, thanks. I've edited my post with my tests and the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I've just wrote a program to test your code. Notice that in main function I just initialized a NULL pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node
{
    char name[64];
    char type;
    struct node* child;
    struct node* sibling;
    struct node* parent;
}Node;

Node* findNode(char* name, Node* start)
{
    printf("inside findNode, looking for %s, starting at %s\n", name, start->name);
    Node* current = start;
    if (strcmp(name, current->name) == 0)
    {
        printf("inside findNoe, node found.\n");
        return current;
    }
    if (current->sibling->name != 0)
    {
        return findNode(name, current->sibling);
    }
    if (current->child->name != 0)
    {
        return findNode(name, current->child);
    }
    printf("inside findNode, node not found.\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Node *n = NULL;
    char bname[] = "somename";
    Node *current = n;
    if (findNode(bname, current) != 0) //seg fault here
    {
        printf("Error: node with basename already exists under directory name.\n");
    }
}
```

The output i get is(Used Visual Studio 2015)

`inside findNode, looking for somename, starting at (null)`

So as `kaylum` pointed out, this line `printf("inside findNode, looking for %s, starting at %s\n", name, start->name);` causes a segmentation fault. And the reason is because you are trying to access a pointer that is null.

At first you need to check, if the pointer you are accessing is NULL or not. then you must access its attributes or values.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: But Megain said " it prints the "node not found" message. "

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there's insufficient information at present, to be 100%, I think.  But for sure, returning NULL (or 0) pointer from a function is perfectly legitimate in C.

You go inside findNode, it works until the node is not found in sibling, it prints "node not found".

```
if (current->sibling->name != 0)
{
    return findNode(name, current->sibling);
}
```

Then, a test is made which likely crashes, because the current->child is not pointing to a valid node.

```
if (current->child->name != 0)
```

You may need to guard access to sibling & node, testing something like :

```
if (current->sibling && current->sibling->name) {
    return findNode(name, current->sibling);
}
if (current->child && current->child->name) {
    return findNode(name, current->child);
}
```

One issue could be over-writing errors, if some pointers are pointing to locations in the memory stack, rather than to dynamically allocated memory.  All seems well, until more calls are made after stack unwinds, at which point the function parameters trash automatic variables.